# Finding the function for a given power series in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, alternative-proof

*The question is as follows:*

The power series $$\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ k{ z }^{ k } } $$ represents an analytic function $f$ in its disk of convergence, the disk of radius $R=1$, centered at the origin. Find $f$.

The answer is:

$$f\left( z \right) =\frac { z }{ { (1-z) }^{ 2 } } $$

---

I proceeded by a hand-crafted method, ie. I wrote down the beginning of $\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ k{ z }^{ k } } $, and just below the $\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { z }^{ k } } $ and take the sum of them term by term. It yielded into an expression already known:

$$f(z) (= \sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ k{ z }^{ k } }) = \sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ (k+1){ z }^{ k } } - \sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { z }^{ k } } $$

As,

$$ \sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { z }^{ k } } =\frac { 1 }{ 1-z } \quad (1)$$
and
$$ \sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ (k+1){ z }^{ k } } =\frac { 1 }{ { (1-z) }^{ 2 } } \quad (2)$$

I reached the solution.

But I feel like cheating, because the conclusion about $(2)$ was evaluated in the course; also my instructor used another method for this question: She differentiated the power series and manipulated analyticity. I also tried to integrate first, then differentiate by regrouping terms, but neither could I achieve nor could I understand the professor's method.

I'd much liked you help me to find alternative solution -as my professor did- to this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate both sides of equation $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for leading me. I saw it and I was shocked seeing that what I didn't get was so easily observed.